# Does "K" a Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Does the group 
$$
K =\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
 a & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
} \end{matrix}
$$

is a Field relatively to additive and multiply methods about Matrices?

I tried to show that it's NOT by showing this:
$$
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
 a & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
} \end{matrix}
*
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  a^-1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
\ne
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 1\\
}\end{matrix}
$$
But I don't know if "1" means it's the Identity matrix$( a * a^-1 = 1)$. Any suggestions how can I prove K is a field?

Comment: You might want to double-check that multiplication. It should come out to a matrix with 1 in the top left and zero elsewhere. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Consider the map $a\mapsto K$, for $a\in F$, i.e., $f:F\rightarrow M_2(F)$. Then $f(F)$ is a field.

Comment: I've edited, I tried to do that K is not a field. by showing $a *a^-1 {\ne} 1$

Comment: Where are the $\;a$'s  taken from??

Comment: I meant $k * k^-1 {\ne} 1$

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer that $ K$ is a field if the multiplication is viewed as the multiplication from the field $F$ that $a$ is a member of (clearly this is why the mapping works), but I would have to reasonably assume that the question you were facing was asking you to show that the set of matrices generated by $K$ is **not** a field under the conventional matrix multiplication. The is obviously true since inverses and the identity are nonexistence in this set under normal matrix multiplication. But changing your operation as the first answer pointed out, it indeed is a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by $K$ you mean the set of all matrices $\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$ where $a$ is in some field, say $F$, then you can do the following:

Clearly $\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]+\left[ \begin{matrix} b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} a+b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix} b & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} ab & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$, so we can define a ring homomorphism $f:K\rightarrow F$ by sending $\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$ to $a$.  The above computations show that this is a ring homomorphism, and this is obviously not the zero homomorphism, so that it must injective.  It's also rather clear that it is surjective, so we have an isomorphism, and thus $K$ is a field.

Direct Proof that $K$ is a field:  Denote $\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$ by $[a]$.

- We showed above that $K$ is closed under addition and multiplication, and more specifically that $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$ and $[a][b]=[ab]$.
- $[0]+[a]=[a]+[0]=[a+0]=[a]$, so $[0]$ is the additive identity.
- $[1][a]=[1a]=[a]=[a1]=[a][1]$, so $[1]$ is the multiplicative identity.
- Because $F$ is a field, we see that $$[a]+\left( [b]+[c]\right)=[a]+[b+c]=[a+(b+c)]=[(a+b)+c]=[a+b]+[c]=\left( [a]+[b]\right)+[c]$$ and $$[a]+[b]=[a+b]=[b+a]=[b]+[a]$$ so we have associativity and commutativity of the addition, respectively.
- Again, because $F$ is a field, we see that $$[a]\left( [b][c]\right)=[a][bc]=[a(bc)]=[(ab)c]=[ab][c]=\left( [a][b]\right)[c]$$ and $$[a][b]=[ab]=[ba]=[b][a]$$ so we have associativity and commutativity of the multiplication, respectively.
- $[a]\neq [0]$ if and only if $a\neq 0$, so we set $[a]^{-1}=[a^{-1}]$ (which we can do because $F$ is a field and $a\neq 0$), and clearly $[a][a]^{-1}=[1]$, as $[a][a]^{-1}=[a][a^{-1}]=[aa^{-1}]=[1]$.
- Finally, because $F$ is a field, $$[a]\left( [b]+[c]\right)=[a][b+c]=[a(b+c)]=[ab+ac]=[ab]+[ac]=[a][b]+[a][c]$$ so we have distributivity.

Comment: Didn't study homomorphism yet. I can only check it with those 11 statements that check Fields. So, waht I wanna do is to check if one of those 11 statements is NOT true. so I can say that K isn't a field.

Comment: Okay, I'll prove each thing then.  It certainly is a field though

Comment: I did prove all the other 10, does $$\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
 a & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
} \end{matrix}
*
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  a^-1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
$$ is right?

Comment: yep, as you'll see above.

Comment: Thx, so K is a field.

Comment: Thx Hayden!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is not even an element of $K$, it cannot possibly be the "$1$" of your perhaps-a-field.

However, there might be another matrix that can satisfy that role? Remember that $B\in K$ is a multiplicative identity in $K$ if $AB=B=BA$ for all $A\in K$ -- what it does to things outside $K$ is irrelevant.

Comment: How does it prove that K isn't a field?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Who says it does?

Comment: That's what I wanna prove. that K isn't a field.

Comment: by the 11 statements of showing if K is a field.

Comment: Why do you want to prove such a thing, @IlanAizelmanWS ? do you **already** know it isn't a field or it is only a huntch?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: What makes you sure it isn't a field?

Comment: I beleive that K isn't a field, does saying $$
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
 a & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
} \end{matrix}
*
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  a^-1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
$$ is right?  I think no because 1 has to be the Identity Matrix. but I'm not sure.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Why do you think the $1$ of the field has to be the identity matrix? Did you read my answer at all?

Comment: so I can say that $$\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
 a & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
} \end{matrix}
*
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  a^-1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{
  1 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0\\
}\end{matrix}
$$ and all the other 10 statements are also right for K, which makes K a field, right?

Comment: You should say that it is possible for your construction to define such elements $0=\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{  0 & 0 \\     0 & 0\\ } \end{matrix}$ and $1=\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{  1 & 0 \\     0 & 0\\ } \end{matrix}$ that all your conglomerate satisfies axioms of a field.

Comment: Thanks. which concludes that K is a field.